# Exercise with Yoneda's lemma and presheaves

Tags: category-theory

Let $\bf C$ be a small category, and let $X$ be a functor in $[\mathbf{C}^{\operatorname{op}},\mathbf{Set}]$. Is it true that, for every set $S$ and every $c\in \bf C$, exists a functor $h_{c,S}$ in $[\mathbf{C}^{\operatorname{op}},\mathbf{Set}]$ such that $$\operatorname {Nat}(h_{c,S},X)\cong [S,Xc]\text{?}$$

I thought that $$[S,Xc]\cong \operatorname {Nat}(h_c,[S,X]),$$
and the latter should be isomorphic to $\operatorname{Nat}(h_c\times S,X)$. To prove the last assertion, one can say that, for a natural transformation $\alpha:h_c\to [S,X]$, any $\alpha_d:h_c(d)\to [S,Xd]$ corresponds to an arrow $\beta_d:h_c(d)\times S\to Xd$; so we recovered a natural transformation $\beta:h_c\times S \to X$. I would say that the naturality follows from the naturality of $\alpha$ and the naturality of the bijection $\Phi$ between hom-sets (induced by the adjunction $-\times S\dashv [S,-]$); plus, again because $\Phi$ is bijective, if one uses the same argument starting from $\beta$ clearly gets $\alpha$.

If my outline of proof makes sense, can one write it in a more elegant way? I used the fact that $\bf{Set}$ is cartesian closed, but I feel like I could use the cartesian closedness of some other category (that I don't see though) to shorten the proof.

(I'm using $[S,S']$ to denote $\mathbf{Set}(S,S')$, and $[S,X]$ is $\mathbf{Set}(S,X(-))$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $[S, Xc] \cong \prod\limits_{s \in S} Xc \cong \prod\limits_{s \in S} Nat(Yc, X) \cong Nat(\coprod\limits_{s \in S} Yc, X)$.

Here, $Y$ is the Yoneda embedding.

Comment: Thanks it is clear. I only have a question: the last natural bijection is true in general, right? (I.e. $\prod_{s\in S}\mathbf C(c,c')\cong \mathbf {C}(\coprod_{s\in S}c,c')$, naturally in $c,c'$, if $\bf C$ has coproducts)

Comment: @EzioGreggio Correct.